# Laravel Dafault page , symbolic link not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have installed laravel in my shared hosting and everything went well except I cant make the default laravel 5 page to show in my `example.com/` main directory

In SSH I did this:

```
ln -s /home/username/project/public /home/username/public_html
```

when I do:

```
ls -l
```

I get this:

`public -> /home/username/project/public/`

so basically its creating a public directory, so when I do `example.com/public` I see the Laravel default page, how can I make it work when I go to `exmaple.com` to show that default page instead of `/public`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your DocumentRoot to public instead of the project directory:

Apache: `DocumentRoot /home/username/project/public`

nginx: `root /home/username/project/public;`

For shared hosting, you may need to update your htaccess file instead, or try other means, as listed here: http://laravel.io/forum/03-06-2015-how-to-setup-laravel-5-in-shared-hosting

Comment: I have shared hosting, thats the problem , can I set my .htaccess how?

Comment: You'd need to talk to your hosting company about that.